# how to uncache Django model

Tags: django

I have an model called `Chat` that can store and retrieve cookies from itself like so:

```
>>> chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=43265)
>>> chat.cookies
>>> chat.set_cookie('1','2')
>>> chat.cookies
'{"1": "2"}'
```

the `set_cookies` method is implemented with a simple `json.dumps`:

```
def set_cookie(self, key, value):
    if self.cookies:
        current_cookies = json.loads(self.cookies)
    else:
        current_cookies = dict()
    current_cookies.update({key: value})
    self.cookies = json.dumps(current_cookies)
    self.save()
```

The problem is that if if the `chat` object is retrieved in two different namespaces, they update its cookies independently, each one overwriting the results of another one.

Example:

```
import django
django.setup()

from bots.models import Chat

# Let's clean all the cookies beforehand 
c = Chat.objects.get(pk=43265)
c.cookies = None
c.save()

def outer_namespace():
    chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=43265)

    # here chat.cookies are empty
    inner_namespace()
    # Now we are supposed to have inner cookie here - right? Let's set another one.

    chat.set_cookie('outer namespace cookie', '1')

    # Let's retrieve the model again and see
    print(Chat.objects.get(pk=43265).cookies)


def inner_namespace():
    inner_chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=43265)
    inner_chat.set_cookie('inner namespace cookie', '2')


outer_namespace()
```

If I run this I'll get:

```
>>> {"outer namespace cookie": "1"}
>>> # we lost one of the cookies!
```

How can this situation be avoided?
THe only solution I came up with involves re-retrieving the `chat` object in the middle of its own `set_cookies` method. But this looks clumsy.

```
def set_cookie(self, key, value):
    cookies = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk).cookies
    #
    # ... rest of the method stays the same
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another classic exapmle of why you should always normalize your database. Your ideal structure should be to have another model for the chat cookies

```
class Cookie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat)
```

Now you can update fields without clobbering other fields by using the `.update` method on the queryset. set in your own thread or other threads. You don't have to keep re-reading the data before each save.

If for some compelling reason you are unable to convert your design to the correct one, you should at least invest in using a JsonField for your cookies. JSONField is only availble for postgresql at the moment but there are third party plugins for other dbs.